# kubectl apply fails as if providing mutually exclusive options

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to update a k8s `deployment` using a `kubectl apply` command. The deployment already exists in the cluster, and was created with the same YAML file provided now to the `apply` command, but with slight changes.

```sh
$ kubectl apply –f ./my_app_deployment_update.yaml
error: must specify one of -f and -k
```

This problem also arose when creating the object the first time, but I workaround it at that point by using `kubectl create`.

Of course, the file is available in the current folder. Also I've checked I've no alias defined as `kubectl`, so the actual command I'm running is just the `kubectl` you're seeing above.

Finally, my `kubectl` version is:

```sh
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23", GitVersion:"v1.23.4", GitCommit:"e6c093d87ea4cbb530a7b2ae91e54c0842d8308a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-02-16T12:30:48Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.12", GitCommit:"e2a822d9f3c2fdb5c9bfbe64313cf9f657f0a725", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-05-06T05:09:48Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.17", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
WARNING: version difference between client (1.23) and server (1.15) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1
```

I'm aware of the warning above, but I can't either reduce my `kubectl` current version (because I work with +1 clusters) nor currently update the `k8s` version in the cluster. Besides IMO a client/server version mismatch shouldn't be the reason for the error above, regarding arguments provided to the client itself.

Finally, I've been checking the docs but I don't find anything useful for troubleshooting, nor even for the `-k` option itself.

Any idea about what is happening or how to solve it? Maybe I misunderstood something at a higher level about the usage of `kubectl apply`?

### Update 1

I've checked [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60352685/kubernetes-error-error-unknown-command-f-xxxx-yaml) with the same error, but I've no indentation error. Linter doesn't complain, online validator also says it's OK, and `create` command didn't complain about anything so the file's indentation was OK all the time.

It doesn't seem a very user-friendly error, and can be triggered by other sorts of problem, so we are playing guessing here...

Comment: The `-k` option is documented in the [kubectl documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#apply) (which is also available by running `kubectl apply --help`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was it was receiving `no argument`, instead of both of them.

It seems I copied the command from a powerpoint file, where I was writing it directly before testing. The original character was replaced for another one which looked similar:

```
–f vs -f

First: 8211, Hex 2013, Oct 20023, Digr -N
Second: 45,  Hex 2d,  Octal 055
```

So this incorrect character broke the parsing and for `kubectl` the argument was not being provided. Just replacing it for the regular `-` from the second sample above made the command work properly.